# Teradata sql query with a case-SELECT Failed. 3706

Tags: sql, join, case, teradata

I'm trying to  create a query in Teradata but it gives me REPLACE VIEW Failed. 3706:  Syntax error: expected something between ')' and ','.

```
    replace  VIEW  view as 
select

a.ID_CD,                    
a.SEX   ,                   
x.BIRTHDATE as BIRTHDATE_DT,                    
case when (substring((x.cfisc_de), 12 , 5)=' ') then x.cfisc_de else null end as PIVA_CD,   
case when (substring((x.cfisc_de), 12 , 5)<>' ') then x.cfisc_mask_de else null end as CFISC_CD,               



FROM  table1 a
INNER JOIN table2  x
ON a.ID_CD=x.ID_CD
```

Comment: Which Teradata version are you using?

Comment: Remove comma after second case (just before FROM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teradata supports two variations of substring:

```
SUBSTRING(col FROM n FOR m)
SUBSTR(col, n , m)
```

You wrote a mixture of both. Depending on some ODBC settings this might work (it's automatically changed to valid SQL by the ODBC-driver, but only within a SELECT), but will fail in a CREATE or using .NET/JDBC/CLI.